# What is a root directory?

Tags: filesystems

I know what a root directory is, of course, but I am finding it very difficult to explain to people what it is. I wrote a Nintendo DS application that requires a folder to be copied to the root directory of your memory card, and I often get e-mails from people who copied it to the wrong place and don't understand what the root directory is. I don't think they realize that the root directory can be thought of as a directory or "folder".

What is the best way to explain this to these people?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe you could tell them to put it on the memory card itself, not in any folder.

Answer (score 2):

Call it the "top-level" folder.

Comment: I think they get confused as soon as I call it a folder... like I said in my question, they don't seem to think of it as a folder.

Comment: Well, you know too... you've got to have at least *some* level of computer literacy to, you know, operate a computer.  I think if they're having that much trouble, they might be out of luck. :)

Answer (score 1):

For them, the root directory is the first folder they see when the double click the memory card icon.

Answer (score 1):

What about using a metaphore:

You can see the folders structure as a tree. Each folder is a branch with subbranches and leaves (the files). Each branch is connected to an other (bigger branch) except one. The root.

Answer (score 1):

Could you create a simple extractor/installer that will do it all for them?, could save a lot of hassle for the non-tech people.

Answer (score 0):

Make them visualize it as one of those Russian dolls where the larger one holds all the remaining dolls and one by one they decrease in size.Or much like a family tree. The root directory is adam...as in adam and eve and the rest are the offspring branching outwards from Adam the highest person on the tree.